# NotImplementedError, How to save weight file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want save weights file but appear this error message, I use same code in Unet there is not any problem, but in InceptionV4 have this error message.

```
NotImplementedError
Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable. Consider saving to the Tensorflow SavedModel format (by setting save_format="tf") or using `save_weights`.
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\main.py", line 119, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_datagen, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=500, validation_data=val_datagen, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
NotImplementedError: Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable. Consider saving to the Tensorflow SavedModel format (by setting save_format="tf") or using `save_weights`.
```

```
model = model_incetionV4
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss=categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weight/123467_InceptionV4_test1.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(train_datagen, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=500, validation_data=val_datagen, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

I think maybe is model got wrong data so it can not save weight,because I reshape label to confirm to InceptionV4 shape(batch_size, num_classes),and I got wrong loss

```
25/30 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 968272.9375 - accuracy: 0.0800
```

```
class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        #y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_classes))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes))

        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):

            image = np.load(image_path)
            label = np.load(label_path)

            ...
            label_one_hot = to_categorical(label, num_classes=self.n_classes)
            y_label = np.sum(label_one_hot, axis=(0, 1, 2))  
            y_label = np.expand_dims(y_label, axis=0)
            X[i,] = image
            y[i,] = y_label
        return X, y
```

```
class InceptionV4(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,blocksList,num_classes):
        super(InceptionV4, self).__init__()
        self.stem=self.Stem()
        self.inceptionA=self.inception_A(blocksList[0])
        self.redA=self.reductionA()
        self.inceptionB=self.inception_B(blocksList[1])
        self.redB=self.reductionB()
        self.inceptionC=self.inception_C(blocksList[2])

        self.avgpool=layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.dropout=layers.Dropout(rate=0.8)
        self.dense=layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
        self.softmax=layers.Activation('softmax')
```

My questions are:

1. I want to save weights file, how to fix this error?
2. I reshape label from (batch_size, 299, 299, num_classes) to (batch_size, num_classes) to confirm to InceptionV4 output shape, I don't know if this action is correct or not.

Comment: Hi @user888777, You need to define the model as [Sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model) or [Functional](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional_api) before saving it in `hdf5` format as the error stats or do not define the saving format while saving the model which will save the model automatically in `.tf` format or you can use [`save_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#manually_save_weights) method. Thank you.